# TFS API - how to make sure Workspace.OwnerIdentifier is not null?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I have the following code

```
var ws = vcs.GetWorkspace(wsName, vcs.AuthorizedUser);
```

However, `ws.OwnerIdentifier` is null at this point. What I do next to get the value is:

```
ws.Update(new UpdateWorkspaceParameters { Computer = ws.Computer });
```

And then `ws.OwnerIdentifier` is no longer null.

There must be a better way to obtain `ws.OwnerIdentifier` in my scenario. Any ideas?

Our back-end is TFS 2017.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? If you're not using this, I'd try it first: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/

Comment: TFS 2015, but I may not be using the right methods.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the `ws.OwnerIdentifier` value correctly with the NuGet package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) installed. Tried with Version 15.xxx and 14.xx, both worked.

You need to specify the `wsName` with quotes: ([See VersionControlServer.GetWorkspace Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138958(v=vs.120).aspx))

```
var ws = vcs.GetWorkspace("wsName", vcs.AuthorizedUser);
```

***Below sample for your reference:***

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

namespace _0912_GetWorkSpaceIdentifier
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string collection = @"http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
            var tfsServer = new Uri(collection);
            var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsServer);
            var vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            var ws = vcs.GetWorkspace("LC0706-2", vcs.AuthorizedUser);
            var idf = ws.OwnerIdentifier;

            Console.WriteLine(idf);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the same code I have. Do you mean ExtendedClient presents the same API, but different implementation?

Comment: @mark No, I just checked the `GetWorkspace` method to get the `ws.OwnerIdentifier`, and the value is not `Null`. Normally it will retrieve 
 the value once you specify the correct conditions for the method if the workspace exists there. So, if you still get the null value, you can try the _**ExtendedClient**_, as it works for me with the same code. You can also try other [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getworkspace%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) eg, `GetWorkspace(String)`